# Make a recursive function for computing a matrix faster

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I have a function below called `inverseKostkaHelper` (see belos) which
I want to make faster.
It takes two integer partitions as arguments, (both with the same total sum).
The outputs are integers, and I will want to compute this
for every pair of integer partitions, meaning that essentially, I want to compute the matrix

```
Table[
    inverseKostkaHelper[Reverse@lam,Reverse@mu]
    ,{mu, IntegerPartitions[deg]},
{lam, IntegerPartitions[deg]}];
```

as fast as possible. The function `inverseKostkaHelper` works on integer partitions
where part sizes appear in increasing order, as the code is simpler.
Is there a way to make this into a compiled function, or
do some other trick to increase the computation speed?

```
PartitionPartCount[{}]:={};
PartitionPartCount[lam_List] := Normal[SparseArray[#1 -> #2 & @@@ Tally[ DeleteCases[lam,0]  ]]];

inverseKostkaHelper[mu_List, mu_List] := 1;
inverseKostkaHelper[lam_List, {i_Integer}] := Boole[lam==={i}];
inverseKostkaHelper[lam_List, mu_List] := inverseKostkaHelper[lam, mu] = If[
    
    Max[mu]==1, 
            (* Special case if mu=11...1 *)
            With[{n=Tr@lam}, (-1)^(n - Length[lam]) Multinomial @@ (PartitionPartCount@lam)]
            ,
    Sum[
        With[{pos = Position[lam, mu[[j]] + j - 1, 1, 1]},
            If[pos == {}, 0
                , (-1)^(j-1)
                inverseKostkaHelper[
                    (* Remove a part equal to p *)
                    ReplacePart[lam, pos -> Nothing]
                    ,
                        (* Subtract 1 from the first j-1 entries, and drop jth entry *)
                        MapAt[If[#==1,Nothing,#-1]&, Drop[mu, {j}], List/@Range[j-1] ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
, {j, Length@mu}]
];
```

This function is the core for a bunch of computations with [symmetric functions](http://symmetricfunctions.com/),
the package is open-source available on [github](https://github.com/PerAlexandersson/Mathematica-packages) in case anyone is interested.